# C# Make drop down list start on assigned value

Tags: c#, gridview, drop-down-menu, popup, kendo-ui

I have made a C# Gridview, where each individual row has an edit button. When pressed, it is set up to be a popup edit window, where I have a text field, a date field, and a dropdown list with two options that represents the type (company or postal). However, when the popup edit window opens, the dropdown list is always selected by default on Company, and if Update is pressed it will change it if it is on Postal. I was wondering how to make the dropdown list look at which option is already assigned to the row that is being edited, and start there as apposed to always starting on Company.

Here is the code I used to turn the Type field into a dropdown list.

```
<div class="editor-field" style="margin-left:33%">
    @Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(model => model.Type).BindTo(new string[] { "J&J", "Postal" })
</div>
```

This code is in a Shared EditorTemplate under the views section, which connects to my main view through an @model statement.

Comment: To try to simplify, the issue is: if someone wants to edit a row, and goes in to only change the date, it will also change the Type to Company because the dropdownlist is automatically set on Company, as apposed to being selected on the already assigned field.

Comment: Wait, I made a mistake. The way I set it up, it already does this automatically, but because I, in my testing phase, had the Type set to a different value (testrow1, testrow2, etc), because it was a value not in the SQL database, it automatically put it as the first selection.